# How can navigation to a site be done with a cookie when the cookies for that site have been deleted?

Tags: http, cookies, browser, http-headers

When I click on [this link](https://shareasale.com/r.cfm?b=765793&u=1473495&m=5008&urllink=&afftrack=&afftrack=2530), or any other sharasale affiliate link that is associated with the person I'm working for, I notice (via the Network panel in DevTools) that the request is being made with a cookie. To my knowledge, in order to set a cookie without any scripting, you need to receive a `Set-Cookie` header from a previous request. So how can this request be made with cookie if I have no cookies for sharasale.com, as it is the first request to the website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my first visit to the provided link my browser did not send any cookies to shareasale.com however the server responded with a cookie for my browser to set. On my second visit my browser did send a cookie to the server in the header. See screenshots below.

You might not be recording your very first visit to the page. Try to clear your cookies or visit the site with a new "incognito browser window" and make sure to have the devtools open *before* you make your first request. Also the "preserve log" option might help as the network log sometimes gets flushed when your browser is getting redirected.

If this is not the case I suspect you might be mixing the information in the request header with the response header.

Screenshots of my first and second visit to the page:
[image: First visit sends no cookies to the server]

[image: Second visit does send a cookie to the server]

Hope this helps.

**Edit (Adding solution as per comments):**
An incognito window will keep any cookies that has been set during that same session even if you open up the page again in a new tab in the same incognito window as you have previously visited it with. You have to close the incognito window (all incognito windows if I am not mistaken) in order for your incognito cookies to be cleared. Then open up a new incognito window and you should be on a fresh slate so to speak.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/kOeoBbg what am I doing wrong? Although I will say that sometimes I did get the expected behaviour of no cookie.

Comment: I don't know about your habits with the incognito window, but that window will keep any cookies that has been set _during that same session_ even if you open up the page again in a new tab in the same incognito window as you have previously visited it with. You have to close the incognito window (_all_ incognito windows if I am not mistaken) in order for your _incognito cookies_ to be cleared. Then open up a new incognito window and you should be on a fresh slate so to speak.

Comment: that does seem to be correct (also why can't I @ you?)

Comment: I have added the comment as part of the solution. (I don't know why you can't @ mention me)

Comment: @Mason It seems like this solves your problem. Please mark as answer and reward bounty.

Comment: wow it's good that you did that, I looked at the page and saw that there were three days left but it just hadn't refreshed.